# Xamarin form: How to load a file on iOS

Tags: ios, file, xamarin, loading

```
 var canOpen = UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(new NSUrl(actionLabel.ActionContent));

  if (canOpen)
       UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(actionLabel.ActionContent));
```

This is the file stored in my application

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B03E81A2-8A86-4CE8-9846-CAE9D6977330/Documents/../Library/site_4/profile_media/a372419a-969d-4642-bfb5-12bb98074aab.png

I can't load the file with default application on the default. I tried adding file:// at the beginning but still not load

Comment: do you want to open the file in YOUR app, or to send it to another app to open?

Comment: To other app to open, e.g. Adobe pdf or even on Safari will do. If images is better to open with gallery app on iOS

Comment: What is the value of `actionLabel.ActionContent`?

Comment: The file path shown at the question inside the quote